# Persistent storage in Xamarin.Mac application

Tags: macos, persistent-storage, xamarin.mac

I am creating a program that will be submitted to AppStore to be distributed on Mac OS. The application needs to store several user settings in an xml file on file system.

I am using Xamarin.Mac (aka Monomac) platform to create a program.

Where is my app supposed to save application User-specific data on filesystem?

Perhaps, Xamarin.Mac already has some classes to provide developer with an encapsulated way to access these.

Comment: package: 'MonoMac.Foundation' provides NSUserDefaults that would help  save new preferences or access existing ones. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-nsuserdefaults--mobile-6039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find app preferences in $HOME/Library/Preferences folder.